# class(with static member) initialization in c++

Tags: c++, static, instantiation

I was trying to understand `friend` functions and I found myself writing the following code

though I have understood the friend functions, this code leaves me with new ***questions:***

1. how does the class initialise here when I havn't instantiaied any object

> I know `static` member is shared by all objects of the class and is initialized to zero when the first object is created

2. at what point does the variables `base_i` and `derived_i` get assigned to respective values from code

> I suppose it happens at
> `return derived::derived_i + derived::base_i;`

3. if so, does that also allocate the memory for all the other members of class at that point, specifically also for `newVar` in this case

```
#include <iostream>

class base
{
private:
    static int base_i;
    float newVar;
public:
    friend int addClasses();
};

int base::base_i = 5;

class derived : private base
{
private:
    static int derived_i;
public:
    friend int addClasses();
};

int derived::derived_i = 3;

int addClasses()
{
    return derived::derived_i + derived::base_i;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<addClasses()<<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how does the class initialise here when I havn't instantiaied any object

You've initialised the variable in its definition:

> ```
> int base::base_i = 5; // <-- the initialiser
> ```

The language implementation takes care of the rest.

---

> at what point does the variables base_i and derived_i get assigned to respective values from code

Non-local variables with static storage duration are initialised before `main` is called.

---

> does that also allocate the memory for all the other members of class at that point, specifically also for newVar in this case

Memory for non-static member variables is "allocated" when memory for instance of the class is allocated. You didn't instantiate the class in the example program.